# Quaternions vs Axis + angle

Tags: axis, angle, quaternions

I have been trying to find the difference between the 2 but to no luck minus this

> The primary diff erence between
>   the two representations is that a quaternion’s axis of rotation is scaled
>   by the sine of the half angle of rotation, and instead of storing the angle in the
>   fourth component of the vector, we store the cosine of the half angle.

I have no idea what

> sine of the half angle of rotation

or

> cosine of the half angle

means?

Comment: Possibly belongs on [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 13):

Quaternios and Axis-angle are both representations of 3D rotations/orientations and both have pro's and cons.

Axis-angle: represents the rotation by its angle *a* and the rotation axis **n**. For example, a rotation of 180 degrees around the Y-Axis would be represented as *a* = 180, **n**= {0,1,0}. The representation is very intuitive, but for actually applying the rotation, another representation is required, such as a quaternion or rotation matrix.

Quaternion: represents a rotation by a 4D vector. Requires more math and is less intuitive, but is a much more powerful representation. Quaternions are easily interpolated (blending) and it is easy to apply them on 3D point. These formula's can easily be found on the web. Given a rotation of *a* radians about a normalized axis **n**, the quaternion 4D vector will be {cos *a*/2, (sin *a*/2) n_x, (sin *a*/2) n_y, (sin *a*/2) n_z}. That's where the sine and cosine of the half angle come from.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are there any powerful representations that use less math but maybe use more numbers? I assume that you could pile up Axis-Angle representations to mimic Euclidean for example.

Comment: @Aaron Franke I sometimes use a vector representation where the direction of the vector is the rotation axis and the norm of the vector the rotation. I believe this is sometimes called the ``Exponential Map`` or ``Quaternion Log``. If two of these are close together, you can actually Euclidean interpolate between them.

Comment: ok but quaternion still represents a rotation of n degrees(or radians) around an axis so where is the difference ? interpolations between quaternions ?

Comment: Axis-angle can be represented with only 3 parameters, e.g elevation and azimuth for the axis, and then the rotation angle.

Comment: The first line here is wrong, Axis-angle is only 3D!

Answer (score 4):

It means that if you, for example, want to make a 180deg rotation around the Z axis (0,0,1), then the quaternion's real part will be `cos(180deg/2)=0`, and its imaginary part will be `sin(180deg/2)*(0,0,1)=(0,0,1)`. That's `q=0+0i+0j+1k`. 90-degree rotation will give you `q=cos(90deg/2)+sin(90deg/2)*(0i+0j+1k)=sqrt(2)/2+0i+0j+sqrt(2)/2*k`, and so on.

OTOH, if you're asking what sine and cosine are, check if your languange provides `sin()` and `cos()` functions (their arguments will probably be in radians, though), and check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine.